# Unhandled rejection TypeError: Role.Create is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have got stuck on a .create is not a function error when I am trying to repopulate my database when I restart nodemon. I have had this working previously and all the tables populated fine I keep getting flagged this error. I am using Node, Express, Sequelize and Postgres pgAdmin4.

I have read on similar topics that a ; in node can cause errors like this but i have tried a few things and still get the same error.

```
//const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require ("body-parser");
// const { Sequelize, Op, Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
// import authRoute from './server/routes/auth.routes';
// import postRoutes from './server/routes/diveLog.routes';
const cors = require("cors");

// creates an en express app
const app = express();

// set origin to 5002
// var corsOptions = {
//    origin: "http://localhost:5002"
//}
 // add bp and cors using api.use method

// parse requests of content type app/json
// app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    );
    next();
});

// parse requests of content-type
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//bp used to process form data as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//database
const db = require("./server/models");
//const sequelize = require("pg");
const Role = db.userRole;
//const DivingSchool = db.approvedDivingSchool;
const Current = db.currentLevel;
const DiveType = db.diveType;
const DiveRegion = db.diveRegion;
const Visibility = db.visibilityLevel;
const DiveAgency = db.diveAgency;
const Certifications = db.diveCertification;
const MarineType = db.marineType;

//const user = db.userLogin;

try {
    db.sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection made to the database made.');
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('unable to connect:', error);
}

// db.sequelize.sync();
// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
db.sequelize.sync({ force: false })
    .then(() => {
    console.log(`Drop and resync database with { force: true }`)
    initial()
});

// simple route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "connected to the sustainable scuba database." });
});

// routes
require('./server/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./server/routes/user.routes')(app);
require('./server/routes/diveLog.routes')(app);
require('./server/routes/diveSchool.routes')(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is now running on PORT ${PORT}.`);
});


function initial() {

     Role.create({
            userRoleID: 1,
            userRoleName: "User"
         });
         Role.create({
               userRoleID: 2,
               userRoleName: "School"
         });
         Role.create({
               userRoleID: 3,
               userRoleName: "SiteAdmin"
         });
         Role.create({
               userRoleID: 4,
               userRoleName: "SuperUser"
         });
}
```

Error message:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Role.create is not a function

    at initial (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\server.js:86:11)

    at C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\server.js:63:5

    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\relea

se\util.js:16:23)

    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_mo

dules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)

    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\blueb

ird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)

    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\blue

bird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)

    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\blue

bird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)

    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\

release\async.js:93:12)

    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\rele

ase\async.js:86:9)

    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\

js\release\async.js:102:5)

    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\James Greene\WebstormProjects\softwaredevproject\SustainableScuba\backend\node_modules\seque

lize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)

    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

index.js

```
const config = require("../../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
      config.DB,
      config.USER,
      config.PASSWORD,

    {
      host: config.HOST,
      dialect: config.dialect,
      operatorsAliases: false,
        //logging: (...msg) => console.log(msg),

        pool: {
            max: config.pool.max,
            min: config.pool.min,
            acquire: config.pool.acquire,
            idle: config.pool.idle
        }
      }
     );

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.userLogin = require("./userLogin.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.userRole = require("./userRole.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.diveLog = require("./diveLog.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.visibilityLevel = require("./visibility.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.diveType = require("./diveType.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.currentLevel = require("./currentLevel.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.approvedDivingSchool = require("./approvedDivingSchool.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.diveRegion = require("./diveRegion.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.diveAgency = require("./diveAgency.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.diveCertification = require("./diveCertifications.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.marineLife = require("./marineLife.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.diveSpot = require("./diveLog.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.article = require("./articles.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);



/* db.userRole.belongsTo(db.userLogin, {
  through: "fk_userRoles",
  foreignKey: "userRoleID",
  otherKey: "userRole"
});
//db.userLogin.belongsTo(db.userRole, {
//  through: "fk_userRoles",
//  foreignKey: "userRole",
//  otherKey: "userRoleID"
//});
db.diveLog.belongsTo(db.visibilityLevel, {
    through: "fk_visibility",
    foreignKey: "diveVisibilityID",
    otherKey: "visibilityID"
});
//db.visibilityLevel.belongsTo(db.diveLog, {
//    through: "fk_visibility",
//    foreignKey: "visibilityID",
//    otherKey: "diveVisibilityID"
//});
db.diveLog.belongsTo(db.currentLevel, {
    through: "fk_current",
    foreignKey: "diveCurrentID",
    otherKey: "currentID"
});
db.currentLevel.belongsTo(db.diveLog, {
    through: "fk_visibility",
    foreignKey: "currentID",
    otherKey: "diveCurrentID"
});
db.diveLog.belongsTo(db.approvedDivingSchool, {
    through: "fk_divingSchool",
    foreignKey: "diveSchoolNameID",
    otherKey: "diveSchoolID"
});
db.approvedDivingSchool.belongsTo(db.diveLog, {
    through: "fk_divingSchool",
    foreignKey: "diveSchoolID",
    otherKey: "diveSchoolNameID"
});
db.diveLog.belongsTo(db.diveType, {
    through: "fk_diveType",
    foreignKey: "diveTypeID",
    otherKey: "diveTypeID"
});
db.diveType.belongsTo(db.diveLog, {
    through: "fk_diveType",
    foreignKey: "diveTypeID",
    otherKey: "diveTypeID"
});
db.diveLog.belongsTo(db.userLogin, {
    through: "fk_userID",
    foreignKey: "diverUserNumber",
    otherKey: "userID"
});
db.userLogin.belongsTo(db.diveLog, {
    through: "fk_userID",
    foreignKey: "userID",
    otherKey: "diverUserNumber"
});
db.approvedDivingSchool.belongsTo(db.diveLocation, {
    through: "fk_diveLocation",
    foreignKey: "diveSchoolLocation",
    otherKey: "diveLocationID"
});
db.diveLocation.belongsTo(db.approvedDivingSchool, {
    through: "fk_diveLocation",
    foreignKey: "diveLocationID",
    otherKey: "diveSchoolLocation"
});
 */

db.userRole = ["User", "School", "SiteAdmin", "SuperUser"];
db.diveType = ["Recreational", "Training", "Night Dive", "Deep Dive", "Drift", "Wreck", "Cave", "Reef", "Photo", "Research"];
db.VisibilityLevel = ["Bad < 5 m>", "Average 5-10 m", "Good 10-25 m", "Excellent > 25 m"];
db.currentLevel = ["Light > 1 knot", "Medium 1-2 knots", "Strong 2-3 knots", "Extreme > 2 knots"];
db.diveRegion = ["Europe", "North America", "South America", "Africa", "Oceania", "Asia"];
db.userLogin = ["Dummy", "dummy", "dummy@dummy.com", "Dummy", "Dummy"];
db.diveAgency = ["PADI", "SSI", "NAUI", "SDI"];
db.marineType = ["Cephalopods, crustaceans & other shellfish", "Corals and other invertebrates", "Marine mammals", "Ocean fishes", "Sea Turtles & Reptiles", "Sharks and Rays", "Marine Science and Ecosystems"];
db.diveCertification = ["Open Water", "Open Water Adv", "Open Water Instructor", "Divemaster", "Divemaster", "Freediver Basic", "Freediver Adv", "Freediver Instructor", "Freediver Master", "Dive Theory", "Digital Underwater Photographer", "Underwater Videographer", "Deep Diver", "Night Diver", "Ice Diver", "Cavern Diver", "Sus Scub Aware Campaign", "Sus Scub Aware Instructor", "Sus Scub Shark Conservation", "Dive Against Debris Speciality"];

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: It seems that in line `db.userRole = ["User", "School", "SiteAdmin", "SuperUser"];` you are overwriting `db.userRole` definition previously declared as model in `db.userRole = require("./userRole.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);`

Comment: Cheers, got it working. It was initialising it previously with the entries in the index file but for some reason didn't allow it the second.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue with the import. Look below.

*wrong*

```
const RoleModel = require("../models/role.model");
```

*correct*

```
const { RoleModel } = require("../models/role.model");
```